# Android - Using Reflection for Admob Libraries

Tags: android, reflection, admob

How can I use reflection with the Admob libraries so that the code will compile and run even if the Admob Jar is not included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try{        
    Class arcls = Class.forName("com.google.ads.AdRequest");        
    Constructor ct = arcls.getConstructor(new Class[0]);        
    Object adRequest = ct.newInstance();                    
    Class avcls = Class.forName("com.google.ads.AdView");        

    //testmode
    Method methTestMode = arcls.getMethod("setTesting", new Class[]{Boolean.TYPE}); 
    methTestMode.invoke(adRequest, new Object[]{new Boolean(true)});                 
    //end testmode

    Method methLoadAd = avcls.getMethod("loadAd", new Class[]{arcls});        
    Object adview = act.findViewById(R.id.adView);                   
    methLoadAd.invoke(adview, new Object[]{adRequest});          
}catch (Exception e){}
```